# How to load VRML data into CityEngine

Tags: convert, 3d, cityengine

I can't see whether Esri CityEngine supports VRML files directly, or how to load them if they're not supported (the online materials are more marketing-focussed than technical).

Is there a recommended workflow to bring VRML files into CityEngine?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single recommended workflow as there is no direct importer for VRML files.
You will have to use some other product to convert your files into a format CityEngine can read - e.g. KML, Collada or FBX.